# Missing files when listing via Google Storage API

Tags: c#, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am using Google Storage  API to list files in a bucket. It's been working perfect since last week, but it has failed 3 times in last 7 days. I use it once a day, so it failed almost 50% of the days.

I do the listing right after extracting the files from Google Big Query (also using the API). When the extraction is finished (without errors) I immediately list the files using:

```
`var objects = storageService.Objects.List("bucketName").Execute();`
```

This command should return 51 files but only returns 50. When I use the Google Storage Console to check the files, I find all the files (including the missing one).

Did this happen to anyone else lately?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage's object index is eventually consistent, so listing objects immediately after their creation event is not guaranteed. Similarly seeing their absence after a deletion event.